# SQL query using SELECT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very less knowledge over SQL but will try my best to explain the issue.

I have 5 DB tables say **TAB1,TAB2,TAB3,TAB4,TAB5** in MS SQL Server. I am working on a middleware tool to integrate to a DB system. For this I need to retrieve the tables from DB system.

```
TAB1: MAT_ID, A1, A2, A3, A4

TAB2: MAT_ID, B1, B2

TAB3: MAT_ID, C1, C2, C3, C4, c5

TAB4: MAT_ID, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7

TAB5: MAT_ID, E1, E2, E3
```

My resultant structure should be as below

```
MAT_ID,A1,A2,A3,A4
MAT_ID,B1,B2
MAT_ID,C1,C2,C3,C4,c5
MAT_ID, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7
MAT_ID, E1, E2, E3
```

I mean all the rows shows should get appended. The number of columns in each table will be different. Also, I need have an additional requirement to the above as follows.

> MAT_ID will have values like AA,BB,CC,DD,EE etc...

So when I run my SQL query for the instance I need the rows related to individual MAT_ID should get appended as follows.

```
AA,A1,A2,A3,A4
AA,B1,B2
AA,C1,C2,C3,C4,c5
```

The value of MAT_ID should be dynamic and I can't mention it in the Query.

I have checked with InnerJoin but it want working as expected.

I can add an extra field in determining the field for different MAT_ID's in DB table. Also let me know if any other options you can provide. SELECT INTO is also one of the option I am looking in to.

Comment: do you want the content of all the five tables in one table? then you want to use a union all. what are the data types of your columns? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this, not sure if this is what you need. just guessing based on your question

```
select MAT_ID, A1, A2, A3,   A4,   null as a5, null as a6, null as a7 from TAB1
union all
select MAT_ID, B1, B2, null, null, null,       null,       null       from TAB2
union all
select MAT_ID, C1, C2, C3,   C4,   c5,         null,       null       from TAB3
union all
select MAT_ID, D1, D2, D3,   D4,   D5,         D6,         D7         from TAB4
union all
select MAT_ID, E1, E2, E3,   null, null,       null,       null       from TAB5
```

Comment: Hi I tried the above with TAB1 and TAB2 but my result came like below. ' Row1 : All entries of TAB1 and Row2 : All values of TAB2 but with field names of TAB1 '

Comment: yes they do. each column can only have one field name. you can give them individual names, but not for each row. please supply an example of what the result is supposed to look like, even a screenshot of an excel would be helpful. just edit your question to include more information.

Comment: I thought of adding an screenshot of it but unfortunately I dont have enough points to add an image.

Comment: until i understand what you are trying to achieve, i'm afraid i can't help you.